# Append search query (ng-model) to JSON http.get request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-ngmodel

[image]

I am looking to append a search query to a JSON http.get request and then display the order below when the data is received (previously I have accessed all orders)

I am using and assuming ng-model is the solution here, but I struggling to get a successful JSON call with my current code.

Search Page (List)

```
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
          <h2 class="title">Order List</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
          <div class="bar bar-subheader item-input-inset bar-light">
            <label class="item-input-wrapper">
              <i class="icon ion-search placeholder-icon"></i>
              <input type="search" ng-model="query" placeholder="Search">
            </label>
          </div>

        <ion-content class="has-subheader">
          <ion-list>
            <ion-item ng-show="query" ng-repeat="order in orders | filter:query" class="item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap"
            href="#/tab/list/{{order.bkor_user}}">
              <h2>Production Name: {{order.bkev_name}}</h2>
              <h3>Seatcount: {{order.bkor_seatcount}}</h3>
              <h2>Order Subtotal: £{{order.bkor_subtotal}}</h2>
            </ion-item>
          </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
```

Controller

```
    .controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state','$cordovaBluetoothSerial', '$window', '$location', function($scope, $http, $state, $cordovaBluetoothSerial, $window, $location) {
              $http.get('http://example.co.uk/bookingref/get/host/{{ query }}').success(function(data) {
                $scope.orders = data;
                $scope.query = query;
                //console.log($scope.orders);
                //console.log(JSON.stringify(config));
                $scope.whichorder = $state.params.aId;
                //console.log($scope.whichorder);


              })
```

**I think I will also have to edit my ng-repeat too now that it is one single order rather than an array of order**

Answer (score 0):

You should append your parameter to string by concatenate it to URL string.

```
$http.get('http://example.co.uk/bookingref/get/host/'+ $scope.query)
```

Comment: This produces a white screen, console error reads "app.js:74 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"

Comment: @merch89 I think you havent have any value for `$scope.query`